# Exporting jpg files from Lightroom without develop adjustments

Tags: lightroom, jpeg

I am starting with Lightroom 5. I imported my raw pictures from my Canon and made some changes in some pictures. Then I've exported these pictures to my client and it's alright.

Now I want to export all these raw files in jpg without the develop adjustments that I've made. I searched a lot and can't find any clue about this.

Comment: You can also use your camera´s raw development software, since Lightroom does not alter the RAW en any way (all the changes are stores in the catalog) then can can open the folder where your RAWs are using the software provided by the camera and just export without editing at all. (I know this works at least for Canon DPP and Olympus' sw.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to do this in Lightroom. I will outline two of them.

### New catalog

1. Create a new catalog
2. Import all the RAW files you want a JPEG version of.
3. Select them all in `Grid view`, right click, and export them as JPEG.

### Virtual copy

1. In your current catalog select all the RAW files you want undeveloped versions of.
2. In `Grid view` right click and click `Create Virtual Copies`.
3. Now create a `Smart Collection` that searches for files with the `Copy Name` that `isn't empty`. This will give you all the virtual copies in the catalog.
4. Select the all the virtual copies that need to be undeveloped.
5. Go to `Settings -> Enable Auto Sync`.
6. Go to `Settings -> Reset All Settings`.

Some notes:

- The moment you export the RAW image as a JPEG you're already altering the photo. The alteration depends on the RAW converter used.
- If you've custom defaults set-up that are coupled to ISO settings or a camera serial number, the above methods will not work as the image will be developed by default settings based on ISO or serial number.

---

If Lightroom is not a hard restriction you can also use a command line tool called [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). [This answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/577661/141595) contains the necessary commands (adapt the RAW file extension to your situation).

> To convert a single .NEF:
>
> ```
> convert foo.NEF foo.jpg
> ```
>
> To convert all .NEF files in the current directory:
>
> ```
> mogrify -format jpg *.NEF
> ```